# docusign resend envelope issue with Demo account

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to resend the envelope to the recipients who haven't signed the document.

The url = baseURL + "/envelopes/{EnvelopeId}/recipients?resend_envelope=true" is not working with Demo https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/ api.
But the when the prod https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/ is used it is working as expected.

Please help with the demo environment.

Comment: Try confirming that DocuSign did actually send the email, it just was never received. You can use the /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events call or also just log into the WebApp and "View History" on the envelope.

Comment: Thank you Rickey for the pointer. I got the audit_events in both cases Demo and Prod envelopes and think they are pretty much similar. under {envelopeAuditEvent} for one of the recipient. Sorry, I did not understand your comment "DocuSign did actually send the email, it just was never received" . any idea why email wasn't received ?

Comment: Please try again today, there was a problem with demo email deliveries yesterday

Comment: Hi Larry, I have tested it, it worked. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this turned out to be a temporary server-side issue with DocuSign's Demo environment, which has been subsequently fixed.